# Accidentally unloaded all launchctl daemons and now can't boot

Tags: macos, launch-services

While trying to set up some services (OS X 10.10 Yosemite), I accidentally did a `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` and the screen was frozen immediately. Now my Mac doesn't boot any more. The loading bar is half full, and nothing happens.

Is there a way to restore the daemons with some kind of rescue console? Unfortunately, I don't have a working time machine backup, my external hard drive crashed some days ago.

I can still boot into recovery mode, using Cmd+R while booting. I can also access the terminal. I tried a `launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` but it said ‘Operation already in progress’ for every process.

When trying to load the LaunchDaemons files, I was on the rescue partition. After switching to `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` and doing a `launchctl load -w /Volumes/Macintosh HD/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` I got some errors with `File already exists`, but some other Daemons seem to load.

But I suspect, that they are loaded into the rescue system. So I also tried to use the launchctl file of `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/bin/launchctl`. But unfortantely, same result, the screen stucks with a half progress bar during startup.

I had a look into the verbose startup (pressing Cmd+V at startup). The last lines, where everything stops are

```
hfs: mounted Macintosh HD on device root_device
XCPM: registered
VM Swap Subsystem is ON
Darwin Bootstrapper Version 2.0.2: Mon Mar....
boot-args = -v
** /dev/rdisk1 (NO WRITE)
** Root file system
   Executing fsck_hfs (versoin hfs-285)
Warning: couldn't block sleep during cache update
Warning: proceeding w/o DiskArb
/dev/disk1 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
BootCacheControl: Unable to open /var/db/BootCache.playlist: 2 No such file or directory
Bash: /etc/rc.server: No such file or directory
USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 0000000...
bash: /etc/rc.installer_cleanup: No such file or directory
AppleUSBMiltitouchDriver::checkStatus - received Status Packet, Payload 2: device was reinitialized
```

I also tried to reinstall Yosemite over my old system (without deleting the filesystem, so my data is still there). Unfortunately, the problem stays the same.

Now I can log in in single-user mode (I had to press an additional Enter). After that, I set the filesystem to read with `mount -uw /`. Then I load all the daemons with `launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons`. And then, **surprise** it loads my Mac's login screen, and I can login.

But when I try to restart, I have to repeat that step to login (which is kinda annoying…). I also tried to load all daemons with `launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons` when I'm logged in.

Here I get ‘Operation already in progress’. I read something in the single-user mode that the loading of services is not supported. Does this affect the fully loaded OS X too? I'm not sure if I'm still in single-user mode or not. **How can I tell OS X to load all the LaunchDaemons on startup?**

Comment: You might give [single user mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573) or [safe mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) a shot…

Comment: I already tried both, but it doesn't help

Comment: Are you using a Fusion Drive and or FileVault?

Comment: Nope, it's a SSD and no FileVault

Comment: Can you boot into the Recovery Disk and read the contents of the Macintosh HD in a Terminal?

Comment: Yes, that works

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your post throughly. Now I have.

Comment: Are you able to do anything in single user mode?  It seems that single user mode might not go to loading the multi-touch drivers.

Comment: I'm not able to enter single user mode. It hangs at the loading screen as it does while doing a normal boot

Comment: I'm not sure what happens exactly, when using lanchctl. There must be some kind of file, symlinks... whatever, where the configuration gets written. Is there a way to reset this to apples default? Btw: As I mentioned in the update in my question, I also tried to reinstall, same error.

Comment: I just discovered, that I can access the single-user-mode (I had to press enter). I also can mount the filesystem

Comment: Since you can enter Single User Mode try `launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` and if that doesn't fix it then If you can boot to the Recovery HD or a USB Installer you can copy your Home Folder to an external USB Drive to backup your data and then wipe the SSD and reinstall from the USB Installer.  Then get a Time Machine Backup setup and taken and don't mess with system files again until you confirm you have a working Time Machine Backup.

Comment: Ok, backup is running ;) Do you know a way, to re-use my Home Folder during installation? Or do I have to copy all the files manually, install all the applications...? That would take a long time :(

Comment: I mentioned backing up your Home Folder as you said you didn't have a Time Machine backup, it's better then having no backup at all if having to wipe and reinstall if the `launchctl load ...` command didn't work.  As to a way of reusing during a wipe install I'm not aware of a way, which doesn't mean there isn't... I just don't know, as I alway have an up-to-date time Machine Backup before I mess with anything system level so I have a way out. :)

Comment: Ok, anyway thanks for your help! But it seems strange, that an accidental unload of all LaunchDaemons requires a complete reinstall. I still think there must be a way to reset the configuration of the daemons. In Single User Mode `launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` didn't solve the problem

Comment: I have to correct myself, `launchctl load...` in single-user-mode kinda "solved" the problem. Please see my edited question above. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm at a system running OS X 10.8.5 so just as an example there are 237 _.plist_ files in _/System/Library/LaunchDaemons_.  50 of them are (probably by default) disabled and only 42 of them are set to **RunAtLoad**.  So, I'm not sure it's a good idea to be issuing a blanket `launchctl load ...` command on the entire directory.  BTW The numbers presented are for the text based _.plist_ files.  There are a handful, 5, of binary _.plist_ files and I did not check the values on those.

Comment: Reading `man launchctl` and more specifically the `load` _subcommand_ with the `-w` _option_ is says"_Overrides the Disabled key and sets it to false. In previous versions, this option would modify the configuration file. Now the state of the Disabled key is stored elsewhere on-disk._" and with that last portion it doesn't state were _elsewhere on-disk_ is.  Along with other info in the man page and if I was in this situation I'd bite the bullet and backup my Home Folder and do a wipe install from USB thumb drive and count it as a hard lesson learned.

Comment: Yeah, probably you're right. It kinda works now, I have a backup and I think I will do a reinstall at the weekend. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Had the same problem , an answer has been found: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261827/i-mistakenly-disabled-all-services-in-os-x-now-it-cant-boot

Comment: @grgarside The linked question DID NOT SOLVE my problem, the answer here (from @index) did. Unfortunately, I can't remove the "This question already has an answer here:" link, so please consider removing it. And just to be clear: To me, it is NOT A DUPLICATE QUESTION, because the other solutions didn't solve my problem.

Comment: The solutions are literally identical (and the questions are the same). Both index's answer here and klanomath's on the linked question state the same resolution of removing the plist file in `/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/`. If one solution solved your problem, the other would too, they're the same solution. Furthermore, klanomath's solution provides more detail for actually recovering to the default disabled state for some daemons. You do not need to type in all caps.

Comment: Ok, they are nearly identical, but this "nearly" is what didn't solve my problem in the first place: klanomaths answer states that you should only remove the `disabled.plist`, reboot and replace the content. I tried that and it didn't work. However, indexs answer states, that you remove all `*.plist` files in that directory (there where more of them), and that worked for me. So, again: The answers are NOT identical.

Comment: I've edited klanomath's answer to show that all the plists should be deleted. I'm still inclined to believe something else was afoot, since klanomath's original solution worked for the other post with the same problem, and is highly upvoted (and klanomath was one of the people who voted as duplicate for this question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for a persistent fix you can login to single user mode, then `mount -uw /`,
and then delete the launchctl override database.
I'm not sure for Yosemite, but on Sierra that would be `rm /var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/*.plist`.
after that you can just exit or reboot.
this is not as a sledgehammer as it seems. the system re-enableds some of its overrides (from various other configuration files i guess) and so you actually get a nice and fresh override db without masses of "disabled: false".

Comment: I lived with my own workaround for quite a while now, but your answer solved ist perfectly! I did it before I upgraded to Sierra, and everythink works fine!

Comment: Obviously, make sure to reenable SIP (`csrutil enable` in Single-User Mode) after fixing things.