# I mistakenly disabled all services in Yosemite (10.10), now it can't boot

Tags: macos, startup, launchd

I ran:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/
```

by mistake, now my Mac does not boot... Any idea how to fix that?

OS version: Yosemite.

Comment: Are you able to boot into single-user mode (Cmd-S) or Safe mode (Shift)?

Comment: Single user only, I tried to do `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` from there but it didn't help.

Comment: Hmm.  Okay, we're already in over my head :)  Maybe have a look at [this post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192878/accidentally-unload-all-launchctl-daemons?rq=1)?

Comment: Thx, that's it. Actually I'm trying to reinstall the system without deleting user data.... If I find a fix, I'll post there too.

Comment: @klanomath, reinstall did not work. I think I'm going to rename /System/Library into /System/Library_old and try a reinstall

Comment: Ok, maybe somewhere in /var ?

Comment: Had a similar issue, got it solved here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192878/accidentally-unload-all-launchctl-daemons

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The command `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` will force-disable all launch daemons in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ and add respective entries in a *disabled.plist*. The command – entered accidentally – **doesn't** affect the "unforced" load state of a system daemon but overrides any existing state (loaded/unloaded). Removing the disabled.plist will restore an almost default system configuration – except those daemons or agents which have been forced to one of the two states in the initial configuration of the system or after the installation of a third-party app. This can be salvaged by either restoring the file from a backup or – partly – by copying a disabled.plist file from a similar system.

To get your system booting again you have to remove this special file in Recovery Mode.

- Boot to Recovery Mode
- Open Terminal in the menubar Utilities > Terminal
- cd to /Volumes/NameOfMainSystemVolume/private/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd
  Replace NameOfMainSystemVolume by the name of your main volume (e.g. Macintosh\ HD)
- list all files with `ls -la`. You will get a list containing ~20 files - all related to user IDs - and a large file *disabled.plist* (~10-15 KB)
- remove the files with `rm *.plist`
- Reboot, edit /private/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/disabled.plist with `sudo nano …` and replace the existing content – probably some basic xml plist header and one or more daemon, which may have been added by the system while booting - by the following content:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
      <key>com.apple.ManagedClientAgent.enrollagent</key>
      <true/>
      <key>com.apple.ftpd</key>
      <true/>
      <key>com.apple.rpmuxd</key>
      <false/>
      <key>com.apple.usbmuxd</key>
      <false/>
      <key>com.apple.mrt</key>
      <false/>
      <key>com.apple.stackshot</key>
      <false/>
      <key>org.ntp.ntpd</key>
      <false/>
      <key>com.apple.pacemaker</key>
      <true/>
  </dict>
  </plist>
  ```

  This should be the default content of the file in Yosemite. If you had installed additional 3rd-party apps, it probably contained more daemons previously. E.g I had to remove a Little Snitch and a XQuartz related system daemon to get a somehow "default" *disabled.plist*.

Comment: Thx a lot, I was actually looking at that file right now. It worked :)

Comment: @Vincebzh I will add the (more or less) default content of the file. Just a second

Comment: @grgarside Re: your edit. `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` only writes to disabled.plist but **not** to the other (user related ie. 0;248;501;...) plists. AFAIR I tested this with the root user and fseventer!

Comment: That's what I thought, but the OP of the linked duplicate is demanding otherwise: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192878/accidentally-unloaded-all-launchctl-daemons-and-now-cant-boot?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment342160_192878